# GeoKit 1.6.5 not working with Bing geocoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bing

I am using Geokit 1.6.5 gem with Bing geocoder using Ruby on rails.

Ruby version : **1.8.7**

This was working a week ago and suddenly, it stopped searching the address suddenly.

Here I have try to update the gem with **1.9.0** but didn't find any success as this is showing some issue like:

**/vendor/gems/geokit-1.9.2/lib/geokit/geocoders.rb:198: 
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
          body.encode!('UTF-8', 'UTF-8', invalid: :replace)**

Can someone please let me know if there is any issue in bing geocoder starts in last week or if i need to change something in my code to use it.

Comment: It is using the hash key value pair syntax introduced in ruby 1.9.  You need to upgrade your ruby version.

Comment: We can't do this. issue is that it is working a week ago very smoothly so there may be some workaround if anything is stopped with same version of ruby.

Comment: Well you can override that part of the gem to use hash rocket style `body.encode!('UTF-8', 'UTF-8', :invalid => :replace)` but you would have to do it in many places I'd imagine, or you could use a lower version of Geokit.  But to be honest really you should upgrade the ruby version.

Comment: I also done the suggestion provided by you but it gives again error in some more places. i tried with multigeocoder also but it works only for zip code with same ruby and geokit versions so there must be some issue in bing geocoder. I want some solution for the same.

Comment: This issue is now resolved as we have found that Bing key was expired due to which it was not able to search.